# Stored Procedures aganist SQL injection

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I prefer to use prepared statement but i'm studiyng defense techniques from SQL injection. I've read that stored procedures are used to limit the database privileges allowing only the execution privilege on the procedures but in some cases can be used to avoid sql injection.

Someone can give me an example using mysql?

Comment: Well this is the larger section which can not be answered here see in short if you write `parameterized query` then you will prevent 80% of injections already but it all depends on your database structure,coding style bla bla bla.......

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures has absolutely nothing to do with injections.

To protect from injection, you have to **format your SQL properly**, be it SELECT query, a procedure call or anything. That. Is. All.

Comment: Downvoted. The better way to avoid SQL injection is to parametrize you query and the better way to parametrize your query (in most scenarios) is to use SP. Please read this article for a full explain: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/96328/

Comment: @jean Good luck with that, "better way to parametrize your query (in most scenarios) is to use SP",  arguement! :)

Comment: @jean well my scanty web-development skills allowed me to read. The very `it's nearly impossible to attack something you don't know of` statement made me laugh. Try to post it on security@stackexcenge and tell them that security through obscurity is a good principle to follow.

Comment: @jean as far as I can tell, this is on *reducing the harm done by possible injection*, but not on *prevention* at all. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: @jean however, the only question I really want an answer for: do *you* personally put all the database interactions in procedures and use only procedure calls in your applications?

Comment: I use SPs or *parametric* dynamic queries EVER and what do you mean by formatting SQL? Replacing quotes?

Comment: Sorry I missed something? I advocating to use SPs, the article advocates to use SPs and I said I use SPs os parametric dynamic queries. Please read the article and if you disagrees there's a join the discussion link below it. SQL injection is the exploit of using NON parametric dynamic queries. Don't using it is the only way to stop it (forget about trying to replace quotes)

Comment: Dynamic Parametric queries can be used but there's a lot of confusing about it (what is it, when a dynamic query is parametric or not, how to use it, etc) and I usually don't touch this topic in quick comments. Can you point where in the article that is mentioned?

Comment: @jean **please** read your article yourself. The only it's point is that running whatever queries against database directly is error prone. And stored procedures is the only silver bullet and they have to be used exclusively. While all other rights like for SELECT, DELETE and other SQL have to be taken from user - so he would be unable to run them even he decided to.

Comment: No silver bullet, the article put a disclaimer about limitations like changing the parameter value itself and never touched parametric dynamic queries and it's not mine I just found it pertinent as a lot others can be. By the way you wrote "you have to format your SQL properly... That. Is. All." and it really sounded like a silver bullet and you even explained what you mean by "format SQL properly"

Comment: @jean this article *indeed* is quite vague and the author never says openly what he aims to. But from the reasoning he use one could tell that he just **don't give any rights** for the conventional queries to the user he created. Intentionally. But only execute. Means no parameterized query can ever be run in his setup. And so he says in the very preface: parameters are bad because developers are bad. The only point of this whole article is to **forbid conventional query execution at all.** If you find it pertinent - well, try to use it yourself first. And only then offer it to others.